# How to enabling button 1 by 1 which is last clicked to disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do whenever I click button its disabled and if click I recall button it will remove buttons disabled and table last td and it works but it will not work on multiple clicks I want it enable 1 by 1 of last clicks to first click.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/5b6xLpfs/)

this is my func witch is remove last td and equal its name to disabled buttons value then enable button.

```
$("#removebutton").click(function(){
var checkbutton = $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").text();

  var chkbutton = $(".chkbox:disabled").val();

  if (checkbutton === chkbutton) {
    $(".chkbox:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").remove();
});
```

Also I noticed it remove last td of each row is it possible to reach last `tr` and last `td` like this `$('#tablebody tr:last-child td:last-child')` ANSWER `$('#tablebody tr:**last** td:last-child')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/5b6xLpfs/5/

```js
$('.chkbox').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).val(),
    Idans = $(this).attr('id'),
    $list = $("#tablebody"),
    $lastRow = $list.find("tr").last(),
    columnCount = $("#colorfultr th").length;
  if ($lastRow.length === 0 || $lastRow.find("td").length >= columnCount) {
    $lastRow = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo($list);
  }
  $lastRow.append("<td value='" + value + "'>" + "<b>" + value + "</b>" + "</td>")
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});

$("#removebutton").click(function(){
 
  $('.chkbox[value="' +  $('#tablebody tr td:last-child').text() + '"]').prop("disabled", false);
  $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").remove();
  
});
```

```html
<div class="answers" id="ans0" style="margin-left: 2em;">
  <button class="chkbox" id="q1d" name="q1" type="button" value="a">
    <label for="q1d"><span>btun</span></label>
  </button>
  <button class="chkbox" id="q1i" name="q1" type="button" value="b">
    <label for="q1i"><span></span>btun</label>
  </button>
  <button class="chkbox" id="q1s" name="q1" type="button" value="c">
    <label for="q1s"><span>btun</span></label>
  </button>
  <button class="chkbox" id="q1c" name="q1" type="button" value="d">
    <label for="q1c"><span>just btun</span></label>
  </button>
</div>
<table class="classytable" style="margin: 0px auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr id="colorfultr">
      <th scope="col">4 оноо</th>
      <th scope="col">1 оноо</th>
      <th scope="col">3 оноо</th>
      <th scope="col">2 оноо</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tablebody'>
  </tbody>
</table>


<button id="removebutton">remove last td and enable button which is pressed last</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Modified code from actual code**

```
$("#removebutton").click(function(){
   $('.chkbox[value="' +  $('#tablebody tr td:last-child').text() + '"]').prop("disabled", false);
   $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").remove();
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks works great how did you do this jquery i didnt know i can get select like this $('.chkbox[value="' +  $('#tablebody tr td:last-child').text() + '"]'

Comment: You can select an element using `jQuery` in many ways... You can use `$('button[value="' +  $('#tablebody tr td:last-child').text() + '"]').prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: thanks there is mini question is there any way to count those disabled buttons ? you dont have to answer but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

seems like, this is what you want to achieve

```
$("#removebutton").click(function(){
var checkbutton = $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").text();

  var chkbutton = $(".chkbox:disabled:last").val();

  if (checkbutton === chkbutton) {
    $(".chkbox:disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  $("#tablebody tr td:last-child").remove();
});
```

rather than use `$(".chkbox:disabled")`. you should use `$(".chkbox:disabled:last")` to get the last element of disabled button. then check its value

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/5b6xLpfs/1/

Comment: Thanks for reply but doesnt enable them 1 by 1 of last clicked but thanks for ':disabled:last' i all keep that in mind